Android Studio not detected by react-native doctor (MacOS)
I have installed Android Studio via JetBrains Toolbox. Although I followed all the steps according to the documentation, react-native doctor complains about missing Android Studio.

Context:

MacOS 14.5 (arm64)
Android Studio Jellyfish
JetBrains Toolbox 2.3.2.31487


I haven’t really tracked the issue. However, as a workaround, I uninstall Android Studio via JetBrains Toolbox and reinstall it using Homebrew.
brew install --cask android-studio

